# Old piano Power adapter

Tags: power-supply, power, connector, adapter

I bought an old Roland EP-9e digital piano from eBay. The seller mentioned that it was missing a power supply. I purchased a matching power supply, 12V DC 2A. However, upon trying to plug it in, I discovered that the power supply doesn't fit the connector on the keyboard. After some investigation, I realized that the power connections on my piano seem different, and it appears that someone may have installed a different power supply connector. The connector on my keyboard is approximately 8mm in diameter. Is there an adapter I could use to resolve this issue?

[Images](https://imgur.com/a/dAyigSY)

Answer (score 1):

The image shows that the original power connector is a standard barrel connector with the center contact as the negative and the output barrel as the positive.  Make sure the new supply has a similar diagram on it.

The replaced connector looks like a phono or RCA connector, the kind used on old stereos.  Please confirm this.  If this is correct, then the next question is which contact is positive and which is negative.

Once that is sorted out, it should be pretty simple to get an old audio cable, cut off one connector and a foot of wire, and splice it onto the new supply's cable.

Please add a clear photo of the label on the new supply, and one of the connector on the end of the output cable.

Update:  There is a chance that the connector is for a 3.5 mm earphone plug.  This type of connector was frowned upon for power applications because the two contacts are shorted together briefly during insertion and extraction, but some people still used them.  If you have some calipers, can you measure the inside diameter of the connector's center hole?

Comment: It is a cinch connection!

Comment: That doesn't narrow the field.  Cinch D-subminiature, Cinch D38999, Cinch-Jones power plugs - ?

Comment: I think it is RCA cinch.